# Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 49

Tags: macos, symfony, phpunit, autoload

This is my complete error message:

Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 49

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 49

I am using MacOsX10.8 and MAMP. I get this Warning running "./bin/behat ..." in a Symfon2.3 application.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Do it for the file being called on line 49

First check whether the file exist. 
Next Check for read permissions on that file and its folders

Comment: I think the issue is "where is PHPUnit in my machine"? Have I a problem of PATH? I've read a lot of other similar questions. It seems to be a problem tied to a wrong installation of PHPUnit. I "solved" adding phpunit to my project, but I think I have an'issue on my machine.